# How do I use a container of sensor cleaning fluid?

Tags: sensor, cleaning

[image]

I purchased Visible Dust sensor cleaning kit, but don't know how to use ampoule in which cleaning fluid is contained.

Instead of screw cap there is snap-on cap with stick protruding into fluid, in one piece. I can remove the cap, but don't know what to do with this cap.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Ok, I added the picture now. The product is Visible Dust Plus. I have green swabs, not orange like on picture, but ampoule is exactly the same like on this picture.

Comment: When you remove the cap, the "stick" is still attached to the cap?

Comment: Yes, the entire cap, the blue element, seems to be in one piece, and that's what confuses me. "Seems to be" means I am unable to spot separation, and if I break it by force, it won't be possible to close it anymore. And even if I could remove the stick, what would I do with that? It is closed, and the hole which would be created by its separation would point inwards. That's really a puzzle which I didn't expect...

Comment: You'll probably have to contact the company directly. Some topical medicines have caps like that. You pull the stick out and let the liquid drip off of it. Don't know if that's how it's supposed to work in this case though.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the "stick" attached to the cap is to be used as a dropper to drip only two to four drops of fluid onto the cleaning swabs. It is not meant to be removed from the cap.

Pull the cap up directly above the vial, let most of the fluid drip back into the vial until there are only a few drops left on the "stick", then allow 2-4 drops of fluid to drip onto the cleaning swab. Replace the cap on the vial.

Instructions from the [Visible Dust website](https://visibledust.com/products/vdust-plus-formula-liquid-sensor-cleaning-solution/#t2) include the following:

> Add 2-4 drops of VDust Plus™ on the fabric of sensor cleaning swab (MXD-100 Green or DHAP Orange Vswab™).

Too much fluid on the swabs can cause more problems than the dust the swabs are made to remove.

Comment: Thanks much for the answers. Did you try it or that's like general knowledge? So far I removed the cap and did not notice any fluid remaining on the stick. I will try it once more and post the feedback here.

Comment: I checked once more, and not a single drop stays on stick, when pulled out of the ampoule, it remains completely dry.

Comment: @DrazenC Does the tip of the "stick" have  a small hole in it? Is there any part of the top of the cap that can be squeezed to draw fluid into the inside of the "stick.?"

Comment: The last Visible Dust fluid I've bought (a while back) was in their older style bottle as seen on their website. I haven't used their newer bottle, but I've used machine oils and other similar cleaning/lubrication liquids that have similar packaging.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I received response from the company which is in line with my note above. Stick has no any function, swab corner need to be sunk into bottle top.

This is what I haven't tried in practice yet. In video, swab corner is deeply sunk into the ampule, and that's repeated in other end.

In they email, they rep told me that liquid just need to touch swab, which makes sense, but is not fully identical with what is presented in their video.

I am still unsure how to be certain that I applied few drops only.

Comment: Can you add link to the video you mention? Also, can you edit to combine your answers and delete one of them?

Answer (score -1):

Ah, while the company doesn't respond, the reseller gave me the clue!

I have one video that shows how swab corner should be literally pushed into open ampoule, and ampoule tilted until it wets swab corner.

I would have never come to that myself, though I suspected that the stick serves no purpose, as odd as it might seem.

Comment: Can you edit this answer into your other one and delete this one?